# 3D model from rgl/persp3d flickers when rotating

Tags: r, rgl

Rotating my `rgl` model with the mouse flickers (notice the black lines on the bottom of the model, which jump wildly around when rotating). Is this a bug or something wrong with my code?

```
install.packages("rgl")
library(rgl)

x <- seq(-pi, pi, len = 10)
y <- seq(-pi, pi, len = 10)
f <- function(x, y) { r <- sqrt(x^2 + y^2); 10 * sin(r)/r }
z <- outer(x, y, f)

persp3d(x, y, z, col = "Red")
surface3d(x, y, z, back = "lines")
surface3d(x, y, z, front = "lines")
```

My environment

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6
rgl_0.98.1
```

[image: Flickers on the underside of the image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the flickering on Win10, R3.3.3, rgl 0.98.1.

Comment: @Axeman: Thanks! So the code example seems OK, then. The problem could be related to macOS, X11 or the macOS-specific code in rgl. I tried running the same code on another Mac (Mini 2011), and the flickering was more severe, actually. Also, two of the quadrants of the figure were completely black (which may be another bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual reason for flickering is rounding error:  you are overplotting three surfaces at the same place, but using different methods to display them ("fill", the default, and "lines".  Each of your calls to `surface3d` does both.)  Different methods are being used to calculate the depth to each pixel, and sometimes one comes out in front, sometimes the other, even though the first surface (the red one) should have won in every case, unless you've modified `material3d("depth_test")`.

It is hard in rgl to do what you are trying to do.  You can make the solid surface semi-transparent, e.g.

```
persp3d(x, y, z, col = "red", alpha = 0.8)
surface3d(x, y, z, front = "lines", back = "lines")
```

but it's not perfect.  You can probably do better if you write a "shader", but that is hard, and is only supported in WebGL.

The best display for your particular example probably comes if you shift the lines surface slightly and play with the `depth_test`, e.g.

```
persp3d(x, y, z, col = "red")
surface3d(x, y, z+0.01, front = "lines", back = "lines", depth_test = "lequal")
surface3d(x, y, z-0.01, front = "lines", back = "lines", depth_test = "lequal")
```

but the amount and direction of shift depends on what you are trying to display, so this isn't always easy to achieve.

Comment: Actually, both your suggestions remove all flickering, maybe except for a few negligible lines. So the flickering is caused by overwriting/competing for the same areas because the commands are chained. Thanks for pointing this out!